# SELECT <A OR B> FROM my_table WHERE A=5 OR B=5;

Tags: sql

```
SELECT <A OR B> FROM my_table WHERE A=5 OR B=5;
```

Say the values (A,B) are:

```
1,5
2,5
5,3
5,4
```

The result of `SELECT` should be

```
1
2
3
4
```

In other words I need the value from the other column (other than the one found by `WHERE`).

Comment: Can there be duplicates like 1,5 and 5,1? If so, do you want to show the 1 once or twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming both `A` and `B` are numeric values, I wonder which solution will work faster, using `CASE`, `UNION` (both are general solutions) or a query like this one:

```
SELECT (A + B - 5) AS OtherValue
FROM Table
WHERE A = 5
OR B = 5;
```

Comment: Nice, though this will only work for numeric data, of course... the case / union solutions are more general.

Answer (score 5):

You could try this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN a = 5 THEN b
         ELSE a
    END AS AorB
FROM my_table 
WHERE a = 5 OR b = 5
```

In case there's no `CASE` in your SQL dialect, another possible solution comes to my mind, which, however, does not retain the order of the rows.

```
SELECT b AS AorB FROM my_table WHERE a = 5
UNION ALL
SELECT a AS AorB FROM my_table WHERE b = 5
```

Please note that this query explicitly allows for duplicate values in the result set! If you want to see distinct values, you should omit the `ALL`.

Comment: the order of the rows is irrelevant anyway since tables are unordered by nature. I like the union all solution, though.

Comment: For large tables with appropriate indexes, the UNION ALL approach is likely to give a better execution plan.

Comment: @ZoharPeled That is true. The order will be undefined if you don't add an explicit `ORDER BY`. From my experience though the "natural" sort order is determined by the primary key. However, I'd never rely on that.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your database supports case expressions, and assuming both `A` and `B` are of the same data type - this should work:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A = 5 THEN B ELSE A END AS OtherValue
FROM Table
WHERE A = 5
OR B = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a very readable query then use `UNION`:

```
select a from my_table where b = 5
union
select b from my_table where a = 5;
```

Comment: ... unless duplicate values are allowed, in which case you need to use `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a = 5 THEN b ELSE a END val FROM #tmpAll WHERE 5 IN (a, b)
```

Comment: this will also return values where the other column is not 5 (I'm guessing there are values like this in the actuall data, even though they are not present in the sample data.

Comment: You don't need DISTINCT if you use UNION

Comment: And as per the previous comment, this will return `1,2,3,4,5` rather than just `1,2,3,4`

Comment: At least the second sample (after your "OR") will return about anything, not just rows where `a = 5 or b = 5`.